# useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later

Tags: bash, passwd-file, useradd

Trying to add a user:

```
useradd -c "test" -d /home/bbbbbbbb -e "01-jan-2013" 
  -f 10 -g admin -p secretfgjdhdgd -s /bin/bash -u 123456 blobblob
```

but getting:

```
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

Comment: note that `useradd`'s -p expects an encrypted password. Consider using `newusers` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run `useradd` with root privileges, for example by using `sudo`:

```
sudo -- useradd -c "test" -d /home/bbbbbbbb -e "01-jan-2013" -f 10 -g admin -p secretfgjdhdgd -s /bin/bash -u 123456 blobblob
```